# Setup Cypress.io to access a page through a proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, cypress

Is it possible to setup cypress.io to access pages through a proxy?

I have a proxy that I need to go through, in order to test my application.
Is there anyway to configure cypress.io to honour the standard HTTP_PROXY environment variables.. or is there some other setup that is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

This is now well documented at:
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/proxy-configuration.html

Unix

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://my-company-proxy.com
```

Windows

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://my-company-proxy.com
```

---

There is a Cypress issue open to track this: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1469

This covers many of the common issues with getting through a corporate proxy and ways of working around them.

The following is an excerpt from the [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1469#issue-305961859):

> **Setting Environment Variables**
>
> Set HTTP_PROXY and/or HTTPS_PROXY to your corporate proxy
>
> ```
> HTTP_PROXY=http://my-proxy-address cypress run
> ```
>
> Set NO_PROXY for localhost to prevent it from hitting corporate proxy
>
> ```
> NO_PROXY=localhost cypress run
> ```
>
> **Other workarounds**
>
> For cy.visit()
>
> - Enable permissions in the Cypress chrome extension
> - Check the Chrome ProxyMode if you have administration rights
> - Try using Electron
>
> **For Download**
>
> - Try the direct download if you're having issues during install.
> - Workaround for install using `CYPRESS_BINARY_VERSION`.
>
> **For accessing 'Runs' tab in Test Runner**
>
> If you need to set up a project, you have to do it in this tab.
> Fortunately, you should only need to do this once. Try to do this once
> outside of the corporate proxy then you should be good to go.

Comment: What if I have proxy login username and password associated with proxy server

Comment: Will this work to step around DOD soft certs/CAC?

Answer (score 2):

HTTP_PROXY was added and Cypress.io should be able to work with your proxy with that set. I however still can't get our HTTPS to work, so its not totally working

Answer (score 2):

I use  "cypress": "3.3.1", there is a proxy setting

[image]

Comment: set HTTP_PROXY=127.1.1.1:80 not setting up proxy for me. Can u tell how u didi it?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue.
My issue:
My cypress tests are running for one application and due to the corporate firewall, it was not able to access the public internet URL.
Ex. xyz.com

Solution:
I used the `NO_PROXY=localhost HTTPS_PROXY=mycompanyproxy.com:443` while running the cypress tests as env variable.

Ex:

```
HTTPS_PROXY=mycompanyproxy.com:443 NO_PROXY=localhost npm run test -- @profile=profile
```

Use these to variable while running the cypress tests.

Note: If we use the env variable to the box that will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Also what you can do is set the environmental variables in your `cypress.config.ts` file below:

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
  env: {
    http_proxy: "http://localhost:8008"
  }
});
```